# SonarQube 5.x performance changes

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We currently use SonarQube 4.3.3 on a fairly big project with 30+ developers, 300k LOC, 2200 Unit Tests and it is currently used to help us tracking issues on our Continuous Integration cycle (Merge Requests, etc).

With the increase of custom XPath rules, we're seeing a big increase on the analysis time. Moreover, we currently can't run more than one analysis at the same time (the second one hangs on "waiting for a checkpoint from Job #xxx) so this usually makes things slow. We're seeing build times (Jenkins + JUnit + SonarQube) around 30 minutes. With the release of the 5.x branch, we'd like to know if the effort to update everything is worth the while, so we've got some questions?

1. Are Java rules faster than the old XPath rules to process?
2. Will we be able to run more than one analysis at the same time?
3. I saw on SonarSource's JIRA that the 5.2 release (which will detach the analysis from the DB) is due to the 23rd of September. Will this really happen? Are the users expected to see a big performance increase with this?

We're curious to hear real-world cases on this, so any input will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: don't trust release date in JIRA... yet :)

Comment: Not sure your question is really for stackoverflow, still: 
1. Most probably. but there are too many dependencies to give a firm answer to this question : what are you checking ? will you implement it with an optimized algorithm ? etc. 
point 2. is simply impossible to answer without actually trying things out as there are again too many parameters that can make things vary. 

Having say that : as Java plugin developer and knowing the guys from platform team:  I can only recommend to forget about Xpath rules and upgrade to latest versions which are likely to be better.